# Test coverage with Mockk in Android Kotlin Apps

Tags: android, kotlin, unit-testing, mockk

I am trying to write Unit test cases for below Utility class

```
@Singleton
class TestApp @Inject constructor(@ApplicationContext val context: Context) {

     fun getOSNumber() = Build.VERSION.RELEASE

}
```

Below is the sample test case using Mockk library

```
class TestAppTest {

private val context = mockk<Context>(relaxed = true)
private val testApp = TestApp(mockk(relaxed = true))

@Before
fun setup() {
MockkAnnotaions.init(this, relaxUnion = true)
}

@Test
fun testOs() {

every {
   testApp.getOSNumber()
} return 11

val number =  testApp.getOSNumber()

assertEquals(11, number)
}

}
```

if i run above test case, i am seeing below error in console

Missing mocked calls inside every { ... } block: make sure the object inside the block is a mock
io.mockk.MockKException: Missing mocked calls inside every { ... } block: make sure the object inside the block is a mock

Answer (score 0):

`testApp` is not a mock, so you can't mock the `getOsNumber()` function call. You can use `spyk()` for this.

```
private val testApp = spyk(TestApp(mockk(relaxed = true)))
```

However note that the whole point of unit testing `TestApp` class is to test the actual behavior of the class. By mocking a function and then asserting its return value you're actually testing the mocking framework and not the `TestApp` class